# How to pick json object from a raw message string?

Tags: java, json, message-queue, org.json

I am receiving a message somewhat like stated below.
This is just a sample message coming from a server. Raw message may contain many special characters. How to pick the exact json part from the message as we all know that  the json part comes with braces {}. Is there any json parser in Java which can parse raw message format and output the json object. Till now I have seen few json parsers but we have to provide the exact json string to parse.

`"hdr_Tran_Id={CARDBALANCE}~*hdr_Ref_No=1~*{res_Status=00000~}*{\"RESCARDNUMBER\":\"46877801****5006\",\"RESERRMSG\":\"SUCCESS\",\"RESTXNREFCODE\":\"CRDHOTLIST\",\"RESLOCALTXNDTTIME\":\"20190121183606\",\"RESHDRTRANID\":\"CARDSTMTGEN\",\"RESERRCODE\":\"0\",\"RESTXNREFNO\":\"12341234\", \"RESINDICATOR\":\"\"}"`

How shall I pick the portion of the message in braces {}

```
{\"RESCARDNUMBER\":\"46877801****5006\",\"RESERRMSG\":\"SUCCESS\",\"RESTXNREFCODE\":\"CRDHOTLIST\",\"RESLOCALTXNDTTIME\":\"20190121183606\",\"RESHDRTRANID\":\"CARDSTMTGEN\",\"RESERRCODE\":\"0\",\"RESTXNREFNO\":\"12341234\", \"RESINDICATOR\":\"\"}
```

since a message may contain multiple braces and few braces may not contain a json message.

this is one more raw string sample for the viewers.

```
hdr_Tran_Id=LISTOFCARDS~*hdr_Ref_No=1~*res_Status=00000~*{"ResErrMsg":"SUCCESS","ResTxnRefNo":"12341234","ResMobileNumber":"9448925643","ResTxnRefCode":"LISTOFCARDS","ResErrCode":"0","ResHdrTranID":"LISTOFCARDS","ResLocalTxnDtTime":"20190121174837","ResCardNumList":[{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResEmailId":"krishnakumarj@canarabank.com","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,CANCARD DIVISION,14, NAVEEN COMPLEX,M G ROAD,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"4770360117595007","ResPhoneNum":"25582496"},{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,CANCARD DIVISION,VI FLOOR, NAVEEN COMPLEX,M G ROAD,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"5298700103122003","ResPhoneNum":"25582896"},{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResEmailId":"krish_jkk7@yahoo.co.in","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,NAVEEN COMPLEX,DBS WING ,###,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"6082010100018008"},{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,EDP SN CANCARD DIVN,14 M G ROAD,NAVEEN COMPLEX,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"4687780160098009","ResPhoneNum":"9448925643"}]}
```

Comment: Can you, please, explain better your problem? I feel like I don't understand it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KunLun I have edited the post again, please have a look.

Comment: @GhostCat nothing I have tried so far. Directly came to stackoverflow for a quick solution

Comment: @GhostCat thank you for letting me know your state of appreciation. And also thankful to you for defining stackoverflow :) 
For your kind information the link you have provided is just useless to this post initiative. Kindly understand the initiative for which this post has been placed for.
If me or someone else is bringing up a solution for this post it will help many resource including you.

Comment: A short solution could be `response.substring(response.indexOf("{\""), response.lastIndexOf("\"}")+3);`, but this could produce errors if `indexOf` or `lastIndexOf` found nothing(`return -1`). Also this work only if there is not another substring which start with `{\"` and end with `\"}`.

Comment: @GhostCat this is not OFF topic first of all. If you think that you are having links of stackoverflow which can answer this problem. You can link this post to those posts.Every thing has a proper way to do. Unnecessarily you are polluting the topic.

I request again please don't polute this post :)

Comment: @KunLun I appreciate your try. I am actually thinking of a global approach which can help out any message strings.
Thanks

Comment: @KunLun can we try out some regex staffs. What you think ?

Comment: Another way is to get all substring which start with `{` and end with `}` and test with a parser if it is a json. If you get error it mean is not a json. After that you can check if in json is present what you are looking for.

Comment: Give me some minutes.

Comment: @KunLun sure. Even I am also thinking. I expect we will try and come to the best solution to add the best solution for this post.
I am thinking for a java regex as well as Javascript regex.
Both approaches may be useful for this post.

Comment: /[^{\}]+(?=})/g
Can we try and write an API for the above solution both in java and JavaScript if the above regex is an appropriate suggestion from my side.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I give up. It's hard to find the best regex to match json from a bigger string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use String method lastIndexOf or regexp expression. In following code you can find regexp solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String raw1 = "hdr_Tran_Id={CARDBALANCE}~*hdr_Ref_No=1~*{res_Status=00000~}*{\"RESCARDNUMBER\":\"46877801****5006\",\"RESERRMSG\":\"SUCCESS\",\"RESTXNREFCODE\":\"CRDHOTLIST\",\"RESLOCALTXNDTTIME\":\"20190121183606\",\"RESHDRTRANID\":\"CARDSTMTGEN\",\"RESERRCODE\":\"0\",\"RESTXNREFNO\":\"12341234\", \"RESINDICATOR\":\"\"}";
    String raw2 = "hdr_Tran_Id=LISTOFCARDS~*hdr_Ref_No=1~*res_Status=00000~*{\"ResErrMsg\":\"SUCCESS\",\"ResTxnRefNo\":\"12341234\",\"ResMobileNumber\":\"9448925643\",\"ResTxnRefCode\":\"LISTOFCARDS\",\"ResErrCode\":\"0\",\"ResHdrTranID\":\"LISTOFCARDS\",\"ResLocalTxnDtTime\":\"20190121174837\",\"ResCardNumList\":[{\"ResMobileNum\":\"9448925643\",\"ResEmailId\":\"krishnakumarj@canarabank.com\",\"ResCustName\":\"KRISHNA KUMAR J\",\"ResCustAddr\":\"CANARA BANK,CANCARD DIVISION,14, NAVEEN COMPLEX,M G ROAD,BANGALORE,INDIA\",\"ResBirthDate\":\"02-04-1968\",\"ResCardNumber\":\"4770360117595007\",\"ResPhoneNum\":\"25582496\"},{\"ResMobileNum\":\"9448925643\",\"ResCustName\":\"KRISHNA KUMAR J\",\"ResCustAddr\":\"CANARA BANK,CANCARD DIVISION,VI FLOOR, NAVEEN COMPLEX,M G ROAD,BANGALORE,INDIA\",\"ResBirthDate\":\"02-04-1968\",\"ResCardNumber\":\"5298700103122003\",\"ResPhoneNum\":\"25582896\"},{\"ResMobileNum\":\"9448925643\",\"ResEmailId\":\"krish_jkk7@yahoo.co.in\",\"ResCustName\":\"KRISHNA KUMAR J\",\"ResCustAddr\":\"CANARA BANK,NAVEEN COMPLEX,DBS WING ,###,BANGALORE,INDIA\",\"ResBirthDate\":\"02-04-1968\",\"ResCardNumber\":\"6082010100018008\"},{\"ResMobileNum\":\"9448925643\",\"ResCustName\":\"KRISHNA KUMAR J\",\"ResCustAddr\":\"CANARA BANK,EDP SN CANCARD DIVN,14 M G ROAD,NAVEEN COMPLEX,BANGALORE,INDIA\",\"ResBirthDate\":\"02-04-1968\",\"ResCardNumber\":\"4687780160098009\",\"ResPhoneNum\":\"9448925643\"}]}";
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    result.addAll(extractJson(raw1, Pattern.compile("(\\{.*?\\})")));
    result.addAll(extractJson(raw1, Pattern.compile("(\\{.*\\[.*?\\]\\})")));
    result.addAll(extractJson(raw2, Pattern.compile("(\\{.*?\\})")));
    result.addAll(extractJson(raw2, Pattern.compile("(\\{.*\\[.*?\\]\\})")));
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static Set<String> extractJson(String raw, Pattern p) throws IOException {
    Set<String> jsons = new HashSet<>();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(raw);
    while (m.find()) {
        String groupJson = m.group(1);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef
                = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        };

        try {
            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(groupJson, typeRef);
            jsons.add(groupJson);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            //ignore
        }
    }
    return jsons;
}
```

output:

```
{"RESCARDNUMBER":"46877801****5006","RESERRMSG":"SUCCESS","RESTXNREFCODE":"CRDHOTLIST","RESLOCALTXNDTTIME":"20190121183606","RESHDRTRANID":"CARDSTMTGEN","RESERRCODE":"0","RESTXNREFNO":"12341234", "RESINDICATOR":""}
    {"ResErrMsg":"SUCCESS","ResTxnRefNo":"12341234","ResMobileNumber":"9448925643","ResTxnRefCode":"LISTOFCARDS","ResErrCode":"0","ResHdrTranID":"LISTOFCARDS","ResLocalTxnDtTime":"20190121174837","ResCardNumList":[{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResEmailId":"krishnakumarj@canarabank.com","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,CANCARD DIVISION,14, NAVEEN COMPLEX,M G ROAD,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"4770360117595007","ResPhoneNum":"25582496"},{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,CANCARD DIVISION,VI FLOOR, NAVEEN COMPLEX,M G ROAD,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"5298700103122003","ResPhoneNum":"25582896"},{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResEmailId":"krish_jkk7@yahoo.co.in","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,NAVEEN COMPLEX,DBS WING ,###,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"6082010100018008"},{"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,EDP SN CANCARD DIVN,14 M G ROAD,NAVEEN COMPLEX,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"4687780160098009","ResPhoneNum":"9448925643"}]}
    {"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,CANCARD DIVISION,VI FLOOR, NAVEEN COMPLEX,M G ROAD,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"5298700103122003","ResPhoneNum":"25582896"}
    {"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,EDP SN CANCARD DIVN,14 M G ROAD,NAVEEN COMPLEX,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"4687780160098009","ResPhoneNum":"9448925643"}
    {"ResMobileNum":"9448925643","ResEmailId":"krish_jkk7@yahoo.co.in","ResCustName":"KRISHNA KUMAR J","ResCustAddr":"CANARA BANK,NAVEEN COMPLEX,DBS WING ,###,BANGALORE,INDIA","ResBirthDate":"02-04-1968","ResCardNumber":"6082010100018008"}
```

Comment: I have added one more json sample to the main post. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Added output for second sample.
I would choose regexp solution. 
You can find it as second solution in my answer. You can deserialize extracted json with ObjectMapper, check the needed fields and select one.

Comment: Added json deserialization and sample condition.

Comment: have you tried validating the output as a json object.
I tried the second output in jsonformatter.org it is throwing exception.

Comment: @ShuvajitGhosh It's cause of your second example. There is a big json `{...{...}...[...]}`(valid json) and his regex (not very good regex to match json) stop at first `}`, which return `{...{...}` which is an invalid json.

Comment: @Shuvajit Ghosh Could you add expectation for second json?

Comment: What if we can use two use cases for that big json. Ultimately we have to design an API which can support any raw message.


What if we can use the below two use cases.
``
1. {.*?}
2. {.*?}]}
``
Any more use cases are always appreciated.

Comment: @ShuvajitGhosh Trust me you can't include all usecasses, are to much. You need to find a logic.

Comment: @KunLun I am still thinking on it. What I have thought so far I have just shared with you all. :)

Comment: The best regex I got is: `"([\\[](?:.+?)[]])|([{](?:.+?)[}])"` , but here is a problem if you have `{...}` or `[...]` in your big json. You will get only invalid jsons. That's why I said it's hard to find a good regex.

Comment: @ShuvajitGhosh I have just updated the proposed solution. Hope it helps. :) You could add some logic to filter out invalid results.